# Entity Framework dbSet.Include(x=>x.Offer.Images.Where(y=>y.IsDeleted == false))

Tags: entity-framework, include, where-clause

How should I transform this query into a valid Entity Framework query?

```
dbSet.Include(x=>x.Offer.Images.Where(y=>y.IsDeleted == false))
```

The Where clause throws an exception:

> The Include path expression must refer to a navigation property defined on the type. Use dotted paths for reference navigation properties and the Select operator for collection navigation properties.

I already tried third party library IncludeFilter, which works. However it doesn't allow me to use another include:

```
dbSet.Include(x=>x.Offer.Images.Where(y=>y.IsDeleted == false)).Include(x=>x.Demand)
```

Many thanks :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Include is just a marker to tell EF to eager-load related entities. It doesn't support eager-loading a selected sub-set of relatives, such as active items.

When working with a soft-delete model (IsDeleted/IsActive)  will populate the view models with the active children. The benefit of returning view models for read operations is that you avoid potential lazy-load scenarios and just retrieve the data you need to consume. For edit operations I will eager-load related data and typically want both active and inactive records.

```
var viewModels = dbset.Select(x => new MyVM
{
  Objectid = x.ObjectId,
  // ...
  Offer = new OfferViewModel
  {
    OfferId = x.Offer.OfferId,
    // ...
    Images = x.Offer.Images
      .Where(i => !i.IsDeleted) // Load only active images
      .Select(i => new ImageViewModel 
      {
        ImageId = i.ImageId,
        //...
      }).ToList()
  }
}
```

Note that this doesn't need explicit `.Include()` statements, just load the data that you need.

When I go to save changes to the entity graph then I would load the root entity with `.Include(x => x.Order).Include(x => x.Order.Images)` to ensure that I have all relative data included. EF should be aware of the full collection before applying updates to avoid surprises such as duplicate record insertion attempts.

Comment: Thank you, it helped me a lot. Can you please share me some link or book where to learn more about Linq? I'm looking for advanced topics, not the basics.

Comment: I don't know of any off the top for Linq other than Googling, but a good outline of some of the performance considerations for EF would be: https://www.red-gate.com/simple-talk/dotnet/net-tools/entity-framework-performance-and-what-you-can-do-about-it/

Answer (score 0):

> I already tried third party library IncludeFilter, which works. However it doesn't allow me to use another include:

When starting to use IncludeFilter, you need to continue using it all the way even if you don't filter.

```
dbSet.IncludeFilter(x=>x.Offer.Images.Where(y=>y.IsDeleted == false))
.IncludeFilter(x=>x.Demand)
```